# Background image not showing in asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, css, image, background, background-image

I have created **ASP.NET project in my office computer** and synchronized it using **Google Drive**, so that I can open the same project in my home.

Both my office computer and home computer have the same resources.

**I have executed the same project in my home computer, the background image of the web page not displayed**.

Below is the css code I used to display the background image

```
body { 
    background-image: url('/Images/blue.jpg');
}
```

Also I have tried,

```
body { 
    background-image: url('../Images/blue.jpg');
    background-image: url('~/Images/blue.jpg');
}
```

I don't know what causes the problem while **opening ASP.NET projects on different machines**.

Comment: hv u tried to access ur app from other machine within your office...if it works or not. Moreover your image should be accessible like http://domain/Images/blue.jpg

Comment: yes, whenever I try to execute the project in different machines, the problem occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try by giving the full path for the image

**eg:**

```
body { 
background: url('http://www.australia.com/contentimages/about-landscapes-nature.jpg');
}
```

If it is working, then the problem is with your path, so you have to correct it.

To correct the path:

1) Take the image out of the folder put it in the folder in which stylesheet lies

2) Give style as background-image: url('blue.jpg');

Comment: Full path is working, but I need to work on same project on different machines. 
How to solve the path problem?

Comment: @MohamedMatheen I have made some edits to my answer, see it works or not.

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced this problem. As the question states

`background : url('../images/books.jpeg');`

didn't work. However the following solved my problem.

`background : url("../images/books.jpeg")`

All I had to do was change ' into "

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide directory structure? Because there must be something going wrong, something must be different on the two machines.

Generally, URLs in the CSS must contain either a full absolute URL, or URLs relative to the CSS file (not the HTML, or in this case, the .aspx file).

You may try an abolute path, at least for testing purposes, to further confirm that there is a path issue there.

Comment: If it is directory structure problem, how do I have to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
 body {
        width:100%;
        height: 100vh;
        overflow:hidden;
        margin:0;
        background-image:url(/images/background-image-blue1.png);   
        background-repeat:no-repeat; 
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        
    }
```

I have replaced **~/images/background-image-blue1.png** to **/images/background-image-blue1.png**